# How come .getClass forces me to use extends?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method

```
public static <T, U extends T> void method(T source, T destination, Class<U> class){}
```

works fine with

```
O.method(string1, string2, string1.getClass());
```

But if I change the method to

```
public static <T> void method(T source, T destination, Class<T> myclass){}
```

it won't compile. Why?

Comment: Neither will compile, because `class` is a keyword and cannot be used as a parameter name. --- The second also won't compile because it's missing a `)`.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati Don't change the question of someone else. Perhaps the posted code was exactly what OP meant. Reverting the change. Let OP do it, if that's what it's supposed to say.

Comment: @Andreas From questions it's very clear that OP has just mis-typed while trying to hide some project code info. Otherwise Op would  never be able to ask `How come .getClass forces me to use extends? 
` question, as the code would never compile.

Comment: Op can you please consider  @Andreas comment and update your question accordingly?

Comment: What's the point of passing in the Class object? The method can do the `.getClass()` call itself.

Comment: @Andreas you are right! there is no point, it was left over code from before, but I just wanted to learn why this is not allowed!

Comment: @erotsppa still please update question  as class is a keyword in java and not allowed to be used as a variable.

Comment: @erotsppa If you replace `string1.getClass()` with `String.class`, both will compile fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object.getClass()` returns `Class<?>` type where `?` is any type. Hence, for any class you can't determine the type of returned class.

More to understand below is the documentation comment of getClass method

```
 /**
     * Returns the runtime class of this {@code Object}. The returned
     * {@code Class} object is the object that is locked by {@code
     * static synchronized} methods of the represented class.
     *
     * <p><b>The actual result type is {@code Class<? extends |X|>}
     * where {@code |X|} is the erasure of the static type of the
     * expression on which {@code getClass} is called.</b> For
     * example, no cast is required in this code fragment:</p>
     *
     * <p>
     * {@code Number n = 0;                             }
     * {@code Class<? extends Number> c = n.getClass(); }
     * </p>
     *
     * @return The {@code Class} object that represents the runtime
     *         class of this object.
     * @jls 15.8.2 Class Literals
     */
```

More importantly focus on `The actual result type is {@code Class<? extends |X|>} where {@code |X|} is the erasure of the static type of the expression on which {@code getClass} is called.` line from documentation comment.

Comment: Would be more readable if you formatted it correct. Even better if you pasted in (and linked) the rendered javadoc, not the raw javadoc source.

Comment: as documented: [getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())

Comment: So for the OP's code, assuming `string1` has type `String`, `string.getClass()` has type `Class<? extends String>`, not `Class<?>`

Answer (score 0):

The type of the result of `.getClass()` is `Class<? extends |X|>`, where `|X|` is the erasure of the type of the expression that `.getClass()` is called on. The reason for the `? extends` wildcard is that an object of a subclass of `X` can be pointed to by a variable or value of type `X`, and therefore, when you run `.getClass()`, the class that is returned might be a subclass.

Assuming the variable `string1` is of type `String`, `string1.getClass()` has type `Class<? extends String>`, and the argument types `String, String, Class<? extends String>` are not compatible with your second signature, but is compatible with your first. (Though arguably the generics in your first signature are unnecessary, because `T` and `U` can always be chosen to be `Object`, and it wouldn't accept any fewer arguments.)

Of course, we know that the class `String` is `final`, so `Class<? extends String>` is the same as `Class<String>`, but the type system does not take that into consideration. Since you know `string1` is type `String`, which is `final`, you can just replace that with `String.class` directly.